# How to find the nearest point among list of GPS coordinates

Tags: python, classification, nearest-neighbor

I have 2 sets of data. One with coordinates points of different vehicles (`vehicledata`) and another one with coordinate points that are each assigned a region (`sublap` data). I want to classify the vehicles by region. However, there are some vehicle coordinates that are not on the region data. I would like to still be able to classify those points by assigning the region associated with the next closest lat/lon value to those coordinates. 
Any ideas for how to do this with my existing python script?

```
vehicledata = pd.read_csv('ParkingChargingBlocks.csv')

sublapdata = pd.read_csv('location_to_pnode_sublap.csv')

VID = vehicledata['VID'].values #j
lat_v = vehicledata['lat'].values
lon_v = vehicledata['lon'].values

sublap = sublapdata['sublap'].values #i
lat_s = sublapdata['latitude'].values
lon_s = sublapdata['longitude'].values

with open('locations_with_sublap.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['VID', 'lat', 'lon', 'sublap'] 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

for j in range (0, len(lat_v)): 
    for i in range(0, len(lat_s)):
        if lat_v[j] == lat_s[i] and lon_v[j] == lon_s[i]: 
            print (lat_v[j], lon_v[j], sublap[i])
            writer.writerow({"VID": VID[j], "lat": lat_v[j], "lon": lon_v[i], "sublap": sublap[i]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) is maybe overkill:

> kd-tree for quick nearest-neighbor lookup
>
> This class provides an index into a set of k-dimensional points which
>   can be used to rapidly look up the nearest neighbors of any point.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

VID = ['va', 'vb', 'vc']
lat_v = [1.2, 9.5, 1.4]
lon_v = [3.1, 2.4, 2.2]

sublap = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lat_s = [1, 7, 9]
lon_s = [3, 5, 1]

latlon_v = np.vstack([lat_s, lon_s]).T
findNearestRegion = KDTree(latlon_v).query

dist_idx = [ findNearestRegion(coords) for coords in zip(lat_v, lon_v) ]

for vehicle_id, (distance, index) in enumerate(dist_idx):
    print(VID[vehicle_id], sublap[index], distance)
```

Which gives:

```
va a 0.22360679774997896
vb c 1.4866068747318506
vc a 0.8944271909999156
```

The number is the distance to the nearest station (or region).

Comment: This is the error I get when I run that: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sublap_finder_updated.py", line 28, in <module>
    findNearestRegion = KDTree(zip(lat_s, lon_s)).query
  File "/Users/nalin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 235, in __init__
    self.n, self.m = np.shape(self.data)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: check the length of `lat_s` and `lon_s`, maybe it is empty?

Comment: nope, I checked the lengths of both and they're not empty